# How to connect NRF24 receiver and Micro SD Card Module to Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, nrf24l01+

I would like to know how to connect a NRF24 receiver and Micro SD card module to Arduino board. I have already connected the NRF24 module to the arduino board but now i can't connect the Micro SD card module since the ports like 13,12,11 are used by the NRF24 module. Is there a way to connect those two modules?. I'm trying to save the receiving data on the Micro SD card.

Answer (score 1):

SPI is a *multi-drop bus* protocol. That means that multiple devices can share the same physical communication medium (wires).

The only thing that needs to be "unique" for a device is its *chip select* pin which the master device (Arduino) uses to choose which of the devices on the SPI bus it's talking to.

So you can share pins 11, 12 and 13, but choose a different *chip select* pin for each device.

However, SD cards are notorious for not working well with other devices (especially with some cheap breakout boards) and your mileage may vary.